# Log to filesystem or message queue?

Tags: php, logging, filesystems, message-queue

To avoid a "this is an opinion-based question" complaint then I'll ask it more specifically:

"Is logging to the filesystem slower than a message queue, and is a performance bottleneck more likely with the filesystem?"

I am using honeypots in a form and will log details of any submissions caught in the trap.

I will then occasionally look at the logs and make any decisions I need to.

I won't log to the database, for me that's clearly not the best choice.

But should I use a message queue or log to the file system?

I have all the code and setup for the MQ, so that's not an issue, but I'm concerned if I'm more likely to get a bottleneck from hitting the MQ or the filesystem.

Logging to a file is unsuitable in many cases in my opinion, but because here I just need to manually glance at the data then maybe a file is the best choice?

Unlikely to make a difference, but I'm using PHP.

Comment: Define "message queue"

Comment: Fair point. An external message queue service, interacting with it using an API. E.g. IronMQ. The key point being the need to make an external API call.

Comment: In that case my vote is with the filesystem. Filesystem is native and pretty fast. To connect to any api will require setting up a socket connection, sending some sort of handshake/performing authentication, sending the message, parsing the response etc. Using such api will no doubt be slower then filesystem.

Comment: As for logging to a file being unsuitable.. Do realize that mysql basically still uses a file-based storage. So the fact that a "file" is stored has little to no relation to performance, unless you really go top-tier-performance. In that case there are mechanisms that first store in memory and then flush to disk in blocks.

Comment: Thanks Damien. I think the filesystem is the way to go for the reasons you mentioned. Just another quick Q that will help: imagine if this was something done on every request, e.g. something that logs analytics of a visitor server-side, would you still go for a filesystem? I'm currently using IronMQ for doing that.

Comment: Message queue systems are especially usefull for distributed systems. Aslong as that is not the case, your local storage will always be faster then any remote storage solution. (perhaps with the exception of something like memcache, but that is hugely dependend on network infrastructure, disk speeds etc)

Comment: Just keep in mind that in example every request that apache receives is stored in its access.log. I'm sure you never noticed the difference. (ofcourse it's treaded.. probably not interfering with your specific request, but its the thought that counts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logging to your filesystem will be the faster method.

Logging to any Api will cause quite a few actions to be performed, ie. load an api class, set up a connection to a socket, handshake, authenticate, send a request, parse the response etc.

Writing to your filesystem will be the fastest method by far.

Answer (score 0):

It is very obvious as writing any thing to the file system will always be slow. So its a good idea to use a message queue as messages will be written to a queue and will be very fast, this way your main thread will also be freed from unnecessary burdens.
You can use rabbitMQ message broker for example.

Comment: So you are suggesting that writing a file to a filesystem is slower then sending a file over ie. a http connection?

Comment: correct me if I am wrong, we are not sending any files here its just logs. Few chunks of data and freeing the main thread is more important it seems here. Performing file operation in between will definitely slow up the things here. If its plain php logging then that will be the ideal thing to do sir.

Comment: How are you freeing up your main thread if your php enviroment is waiting for a socket connection, handshake, communication with an external api? Your "main thread" will be done much, much quicker when it can just write away the log and close the connection. As for it being "slow" to write to a filesystem, realize that ie. apache writes every request to an access log on your filesystem. Im sure you never noticed a performance issue because of it.

Comment: Agreed with you  Damien Overeem